# can I convert python to an application for android

Tags: python, android, python-3.x, pip, apk

I have a python script(.py) and I have installed some libraries for this script, is there any way I make it usable for android
I have tried to convert it to EXE then APK but I hit a dead-end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pip install kivy
```

[Kivy](https://kivy.org/) is a cross platform library, which you can deploy `.py` to `.apk` and the rest.